# Powershell script presses F11 even if it's already in fullscreen

Tags: powershell, scripting

My script is almost done. It opens IE and switches between the tabs. Half of the time it works and it also goes into fullscreen mode. The problem is, if I execute it a second time, it is already set as fullscreen but it executes F11 so it stops fullscreen mode.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 
"Microsoft.VisualBasic")

add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms     
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"  
$ie.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com")
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.google.com" , 2048)
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.outlook.com" , 2048)
$ie.Navigate2("https://studer-ksg.intranet.koerber.de/de/nc/fritz-studer-ag.html" , 2048)
$ie.Visible = $true

start-sleep -Milliseconds 1000
$IEProcess = Get-Process | Where { $_.MainWindowHandle -eq $ie.HWND }
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($IEProcess.Id)

if($ie.fullscreen){

}else{
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 1000
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{F11}')
}
do
{
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 4000
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{TAB}')
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 100
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F5}")
}
While ($i -ne 0)
```

How do I make an if to make it only press F11 if it isn't already in fullscreen when I start the script?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Is there a particular reason why you make things intentionally difficult here? Wouldn't this be much easier?

```
$ie.FullScreen = $true
```

Comment: I lol'ed, I didn't know about this method, probably he didn't either

Comment: Sadly switching tabs seems to be a bit more complicated, involving keeping track of windows of the IE process yourself.

Comment: I used that in an earlier version but it didn't work because the IE froze somehow. I couldn't even close it anymore unless I used taskmanager...